# Add numbers across a row in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to add the numbers in a row into a "totals" column. If the sum of the values in the row is 0, then the "totals" column for the cell in that row will show a different value. Meaning that I can't use the =SUM method already provided.

My code works perfectly if I'm adding the numbers in a single column, but it doesn't work if I try to add the numbers in a single row across several columns.

For example, if I had a column with 4 rows, and each had a value of (1, 2, 3, 4), the function I created will result in "10". However, if I have a row of 4 numbers, such that column A row 1 = 1, column B row 1 = 2, C1 = 3, D1 = 4, then the result will be 1,2,3,4 instead of 10.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function totalsFunction (customVal, rowValues) { 

  var sumTotal = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < rowValues.length; i++) {
    sumTotal += parseInt(rowValues[i]);
  }
  if(sumTotal == 0) {
    return customVal;
  }
  else{
    return sumTotal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use sum, wrapped in an if statement. Something like

```
=if(sum(B2:E2) = 0, "customValue",  sum(B2:E2))
```

should work. Note that you can even have an array-output (sum per row) when you use MMULT.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MMULT(B2:E4, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E2)^0))=0, "CUSTOM VALUE", MMULT(B2:E4, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E2)^0)) ))
```

For the custom function you wrote, you may need an additional loop to make the function work (since values are passed in as a 2D array )

See if this works:

```
function totalsFunction (customVal, rowValues) { 

var sumTotal = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < rowValues.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < rowValues[0].length; j++) {
  sumTotal += rowValues[i][j];
  }
}
if(sumTotal == 0) {
return customVal;
}
else{
return sumTotal;
}
}
```

An alternative (sum per row with script, array output) would be to use map() and reduce()

```
function customSumPerRow(customVal, array) {

return array.map(function(r, i) {
        return r.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        })
    })
    .map(function(r) {
        return r == 0 ? customVal : r;
    })
}
```

Comment: Yea I tried the double for loop as it makes sense that it's a 2D array, but it still came out no different that with only one for loop. But I did use the wrapped statement with the SUM, and that worked. So thank you for that!